# Can't make the import sheets from directory function dynamic?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros

Can I modify the code below into a dynamic import of sheets,
so I can run it in any sheet from my personal macrobook instead of a sheet called `import-sheets.xls`?

Found the code for importing below.

```
Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, total As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

directory = "c: est\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")

Do While fileName <> ""

Loop

Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)

For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets
    total = Workbooks("import-sheets.xls").Worksheets.count
    Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy _
    after:=Workbooks("import-sheets.xls").Worksheets(total)
Next sheet

Workbooks(fileName).Close

fileName = Dir()

9. Turn on screen updating and displaying alerts again (outside the loop).
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

I would also like to change the directory into a function so I can manually lookup the directory through explorer, without modifying the script each time.

I found the following code online:

```
Public Function GetFolderName(Optional OpenAt As String) As String
Dim lCount As Long

GetFolderName = vbNullString

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .InitialFileName = OpenAt
    .Show
    For lCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
        GetFolderName = .SelectedItems(lCount)
    Next lCount
End With

End sub
```

I think it would be an easy fix to change `directory = "c: est\` into `directory = GetFolderName()` but can't test it yet, because the above code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to solve my problems:

I created `AvivoWB = ActiveWorkbook` and used this in the code.

Like my expectation i needed to change the `directory = "c: est\"` into `directory = GetFolderName() & "/"`

```
Sub Import_Excel_sheets()

Dim directory As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set ActivoWB = ActiveWorkbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

directory = GetFolderName() & "/"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")

Do While fileName <> ""
    Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)

    For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets
        Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy _
        after:=ActivoWB.Sheets(ActivoWB.Sheets.Count)
    Next sheet

    Workbooks(fileName).Close
    fileName = Dir()
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

The code for the function is unchanged and should also be added to the workbook:

```
Public Function GetFolderName(Optional OpenAt As String) As String
Dim lCount As Long

GetFolderName = vbNullString

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .InitialFileName = OpenAt
    .Show
    For lCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
        GetFolderName = .SelectedItems(lCount)
    Next lCount
End With
End Function
```